# can I imply this as the meaning of differentiation?

Tags: derivatives

most of my textbooks and teachers told me that dy/dx is the slope of a function at some point of x
but I observed it such that:
dy/dx= Change of y for every 1x

am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$dy\over dx$ can surely be interpreted as change in $y$ for a very small change in $x$.